# Reorganize list of string and integer by highest integer

Tags: python

I have list ['Cat:3','Dog:4','Llama:2'] and I want to reorganize it from the highest number to lowest. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `['Dog:4', 'Cat:3', 'Llama:2']` - here's reorganized list, take it ... job's done

Comment: I tried max function but it was not going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the key parameter of the sort function:

```
elements.sort(key=lambda s: int(s.split(':')[-1]), reverse=True)
```

The key maps each element into an integer, based on the pattern "STR:NUM". Then, all elements are sorted in-place according to mapped int value.